# 日常にしがみついた's meaning

Tags: meaning

https://furahasekai.net/2015/12/09/good-on-the-reel-searchlight-lyrics-indonesian-translation/

From this song, The sentence "囚われた日常にしがみついた". What do you guys translate it to ?

I did search しがみつく's meaning. It means "cling" "hold firmly" or something like that. But 囚われた日常 is not a concrete object.

So,In my oppionion, I think this "しがみついた" mean "to be obsessed with the days (I) got imprisoned.

Comment: You mean obsessed?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was in rush.

Answer (score -1):

囚われた日常 will mean “my daily life, which is a slave to stereotypes”.
しがみつく means hold firmly.
So I think he or she relies on 囚われた日常 and fears losing it.
If you can’t imagine しがみつく, you can get images of しがみつく by google.